# How to define depth in IOTA?

Tags: iota-network, compass

i am trying to follow private tangle implantation and when I  use bazel run :build calculator command. I am afraid I don't know how to depth in it .json file? any suggestions 
(link I am following for private tangle implementation is mentioned below)

https://docs.iota.org/docs/compass/0.1/how-to-guides/set-up-a-private-tangle

Answer (score 2):

Compass, IOTA's open source coordinator, uses a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree) to overcome the limitation that every key can only be reused once. By building a tree of possible signatures, it can sign multiple times, therefore allowing more than one milestone.

The `depth` will determine the depth of this tree, controlling how many milestones the coordinator can sign before the key has to be replaced (or the testnet be reset).

Increasing the `depth` by one will double the number of possible signatures (=milestones), while increasing the time to compute the Merkle tree by about the factor 2, too.

You can set the depth in your `config.json` configuration file.